# AWS CloudFormation -- auto mount EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, init, amazon-efs

I'm trying to create a CF script that creates an EC2 and then automatically mounts an EFS. Here's the relevant bit of the template. I find that the packages are not loaded: amazon-efs-utils, nfs-utils.
Therefore if the mount command is executed it will fail.
I've verified that my other stack has what I need and the output variable is correct: !ImportValue dmp356-efs-EFSId

If I log into my new instance and do the steps manually it works fine and I can see my files in the EFS. Naturally I suspect that my CF script is wrong in some way, although it validates if I use "aws cloudformation validate-template ..." and it deploys with a successful conclusion. As I said, I can log into the new instance, it doesn't rollback.

```
Resources:
  TestHost:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          MountConfig:
            - setup
            - mount
        setup:
          packages:
            yum:
              amazon-efs-utils: []
              nfs-utils: []
          commands:
            01_createdir:
              command:
                "mkdir /nfs"
        mount:
          commands:
            01_mount:
              command: !Sub
                - mount -t efs ${EFS_ID} /nfs
                - { EFS_ID: !ImportValue dmp356-efs-EFSId }
            02_mount:
              command:
                "chown ec2-user.ec2-user /nfs"
```

Comment: We have a slightly different command that we use: 
mount -t efs -o tls ${FileSystem}:/ /nfs